# How to make footer reveal (display it under site container?)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I am developing this http://37.60.224.253/~silviogu/staging.com/ with wordpress, genesis framework and mobile first by Brian Gardner theme. I am trying to reproduce the footer reveal effect as seen in briangardner.com, but can't figure out how to avoid footer being displayed over site-container while page is load.

Here's the code I am using (copied by briangardner.com):

```
.site-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.site-footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -9999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, you can try any one:

**1.** Assign the background color `white` to class `site-inner`.

**2.** Move the footer outside of the div with class `site-container`.

It should work.

Comment: Hi Bhavya, thanks for helping. I did it, but the only thing I got it0s a smoother effect, but the footer is still displayed for a moment while the page is loaded.